# Java Basic 2D array

Tags: arrays, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(Planes.p_array[0][0]);
flight_GUI form = new flight_GUI();
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
for (int u = 0; u<1;){
    for (int x = 0; x<1;){
        System.out.println("Would you like to book a flight? yes/no");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            form.setVisible(true); x=1;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Okay!");x=0;
        }
    }
}}


public class Planes{
 public static String[][] p_array = new String [5][5];{
      p_array[0][0] = "hello" }}
```

When i call p_array[0][0] from class Planes, it prints out "null" rather than "hello". How can i make it so it prints out whatever i put in the array.

Comment: The System.out.println(planes.p_array[0][0]); is coming up with an error

Comment: planes doesn't look like it's initialized.

Comment: "non-static variable p_array cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: How and where is planes declared ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is how you are trying to access the array.
If you have code like yours you have one of 2 things you need to do. You will have to research the detailed differences between the 2 yourself, but I'll give you a brief summary

```
public class plane {
     public String[][] p_array = new String [5][5];{
          p_array[0][0] = "3";
}
```

The code above describes a non-static class. Plane is only a blueprint in some sense. It doesn't exist so you cannot just call `plane.p_array`!

Method 1 involves creeating an **instance** of your plane class and it will work with your plane class as it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      plane planeObject = new plane(); //create instance of your plane class
      System.out.println(planeObject.p_array[0][0]);
      //the rest of your code
}
```

Method 2 involves creating a **static** variable in plane class, which will mean it can be accessed the way you tried to access it, but you will that variable will be the same on all instances of that class.

```
//the rest of code is the same
public class plane {
     public static String[][] p_array = new String [5][5];{
          p_array[0][0] = "3";
}
```

If you want to know the differences between the 2 look up the differences of "Static" and "Instance" members.

Comment: That has gotten rid of the error, however now when it prints out what i have in the array at [0][0], it prints out "null" when i have set it to "3" (or any thing else).